# Visual Studio 2010 Disable Debugging of External Websites

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am improving an ASP.Net website using VS2010. As part of the payment flow I need to redirect to an external website (like Paypal) to process the payment before returning to my website, however this site has an error in their JavaScript that Visual Studio is trying to debug. I have no intention of debugging this third party's website. Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to only debug websites that are part of the project I am working on or just for localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question. I ended up using Chrome/Firefox to debug with instead. Visual studio doesn't try debug javascript unless you are using IE.

I could then use the javascript debugger built into Chrome to debug any javascript problems I was having on the site I was actually trying to fix.